# atoi function doesn't work in for loop

Tags: c

I am trying to get the output of this equation :

> 44 - 10 + 11 / 5

it work properly as follow :

```
char str[] = "44 - 10 + 11 / 5";
int sum = 0 ;
sum += atoi(str);   //  0 + 44
sum += atoi(str+3); // 44 + 10
sum += atoi(str+5); // 54 + 11
sum += atoi(str+7); // 65 / 5 = 13
printf("%d/n",sum); // output = 13
```

but it doesn't work if I put the `atoi()` function in the `for` loop:

```
char str[] = "44 - 10 + 11 / 5";
int sum = 0;
int i;
sum += atoi(str);
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    if (!(str[i] >= 0 && str[i] <= 9)) {   //if str[i] is not a number
        sum += atoi(str + i); 
    }
}
printf("%d/n", sum); // output = 0
```

Comment: You've edited your question with the "corrected" variant of the loop as provided in the answers, which would've invalidated them.  If  you *have* tried these and the result you expected hasn't come out, then add the new code in a section *below* your original.

Comment: Not your present issue, but since `i` varies from `0` to `100`, you will read past the end of `str` buffer, possibly parsing numbers that are not related to your expression. Replace `for(i = 0; i < 100 ; i++)` with `for(i = 0; i < strlen(str) ; i++)`

Comment: Is 44 - 10 + 11 / 5 = 13 correct?

Comment: There are another errors in your code. `str+5` is `"10 + 11 / 5"`. New line is `\n`. Please debug some lines of your code with something like `printf("sum=%d\nstr+x=%s\natoi=%d\n", sum, str+5, atoi(str+5));`. Take a look at [Adrian Jałoszewski's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39320147/atoi-function-doesnt-work-in-for-loop/39320349#39320349) answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing a char value that contains the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) representation of a number, to an actual number.  Change

```
if(!(str[i]>=0 && str[i]<=9)){
```

to

```
if(!(str[i]>='0' && str[i]<='9')){
```

I did not check if the rest of the code is correct, but certainly, this is one issue.

Comment: Correct wold be to use `isdigit`.

Answer (score 2):

```
   if(!(str[i]>=0 && str[i]<=9)){   //if str[i] is not a number
```

This is incorrect. '0' and 0 are not same. Neither is 9 and '9'. The value of '9' will be integer that represents '9' in ASCII chart.

Rest of the logic seems suspicious too, for example what happens if you have "55", code will enter `if` twice, once for 55 and second time for 5, isn't it?

Comment: atoi function return the number of the given string from the address parameter to the next non number character as an ex:
atoi(str+3) will return 10 | atoi(str+5) will return 11

i get the non number character and pass str+i | i is the position of the non number character

Comment: i understand you , but the statement sum += atoi(str+i)
will not executed if the str[i] is not a number character then i will be the start of the next number

Answer (score 2):

Because your code does not do the same calculations as your previous one. In the first one you are shifting the pointer to the next number and you are adding it to the number, so your code does the following `44 + 10 + 11 + 5`.

In the second case you are checking whether the character code is between 0 and 9, but the numbers are between 48 and 57 - the characters '0' and '9'. So the `if` statement would be always wrong. Your intention was probably this, but it won't work.

```
for(i = 0; i < 100 ; i++){
   if(!(str[i]>='0' && str[i]<='9')){   //if str[i] is not a number
      sum += atoi(str+i); 
   }
}
```

This also does not work, because here you are doing the wrong shifts of the pointer by one, resulting in the reading of the following numbers: `44, 4, 10, 0, 11, 1, 5`. Because of the `atoi` properties. To perform the exact same code you did before you`d have to write the following code:

```
int skip_non_diggits(int i, char *str) {
    while (str[i] < '0' || str[i] > '9') {
        if (str[i] == 0) 
            return -1; //end of string case
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}

int skip_diggits(int i, char *str) {
    while (str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9') {
        if (str[i] == 0) 
            return -1; //end of string case
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

These functions could be used as follows:

```
int i = 0, sum = 0;
while (i != -1) {
    sum += atoi(str+i);
    i = skip_diggits(i, str); // positions i after the current number
    i = skip_non_diggits(i, str); // positions i at the begin of the next number
}
```

**BTW**
Don't use `for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)` to iterate through the strings you don't know the size of. If the string is shorter in length than 100 you're derefferencing memory which probably isn't yours creating undefined behavior. Instead check the `strlen` method or check whether the character is not equal to `\0` which in C indicates the end of the string.

Comment: atoi(str+5) will also read 10; I think he has mistakes even there

Answer (score 1):

This seems a bit odd. What's the goal?

Agree with previous comment.

Why are you doing atoi() on what is NOT a number?

You will go past the end of the string.
Your spaces COUNT in the example

and so on.
you don't update i when you find a number, so you will count "44" as 44 first and 4 second.

If you're trying to learn, hook up a debugger, step through the code, and see how the data changes.

Comment: Please take some time to format this answer. What you say is correct, but utterly unreadable.